# Can this be done with SQL or need to import data and use loops in a programming language?

Tags: sql, postgresql

[Please refer image if table is not clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1Cms.png)

The data contains minute-wise data and number of orders placed within that minute.
Want to calculate the number of orders placed within next 15 minutes of a particular minute.
Basically calculating the number of concurrent orders in 15 minute slot of a particular minute.

Raw Data:

| TimeStamp | #Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 04-11-2021 15:49 | 2 |
| 04-11-2021 15:50 | 3 |
| 04-11-2021 15:51 | 5 |
| 04-11-2021 16:05 | 3 |
| 04-11-2021 16:21 | 2 |

Result:

| TimeStamp | #Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 04-11-2021 15:49 | 10 |
| 04-11-2021 15:50 | 8 |
| 04-11-2021 15:51 | 8 |
| 04-11-2021 16:05 | 3 |
| 04-11-2021 16:21 | 2 |

Comment: What version of PG do you use?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on PG11+ I believe you can

```
SELECT 
  timestamp, 
  SUM(quantity) OVER(ORDER BY timestamp RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND INTERVAL '15 MINUTE' FOLLOWING)
FROM
  ...
```

Could also perhaps do:

```
SELECT
  x.timestamp,
  (SELECT SUM(y.quantity) FROM T y WHERE y.timestamp BETWEEN x.timestamp AND x.timestamp + INTERVAL '15 MINUTE') qty15
FROM 
  T x
```

Or if you expand your times table by left joining it into a sequence of every minute between x and y, then you can use ROWS BETWEEN in a window, which is supported since earlier versions